# Bash empty variable after running cron, but runs manually

Tags: linux, bash, variables, cron

I have simple bash script that working manual at the terminal, but after cron gives an empty variable.

```
#!/bin/bash 
gwip=`/usr/bin/nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep IP4-SETTINGS.GATEWAY: | awk '{ print $2}'`
printf '%s\n' "$(date) =- $gwip -= " >> /var/log/looog.log
```

run: `/bin/bash /test.bash`

output in file /var/log/looog.log:

```
1 monday 2016 14:17:36 +0300 =- 23.18.117.254 -=
```

---

When I run through cron, variable is empty.

```
*/1 * * * * root /bin/bash /test.bash
```

output in file /var/log/looog.log:

```
1 monday 2016 14:19:13 +0300 =-  -=
```

**Why variable *$gwip* is empty? how to fix it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qualifying `/usr/bin/nmcli` isn't enough -- you're calling a bunch of other tools that need to be found from the PATH also.

Also, in general -- when debugging a cron job, arrange for its stderr to go to a file, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

# log stdout and stderr to two different files
exec >>/var/log/looog.log 2>>/var/log/looog.err.log

# ...and log every command we try to execute to stderr (aka looog.err.log)
set -x

# set a PATH variable
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin

# original code here, using modern POSIX $() syntax, vs old hard-to-nest ``
gwip=$(nmcli dev list iface eth0 | awk '/IP4-SETTINGS[.]GATEWAY:/ { print $2}')
printf '%s\n' "$(date) =- $gwip -= "
```

---

The key things here are the explicitly-set PATH (not having the value you expect set in PATH is a common issue in cron jobs), and the stderr log (which ensures that any other issues can be identified by reading its contents).

Note the use of a single redirection to `looog.log` up-front. This doesn't make a significant difference when you're literally only running one print statement, but if you would have extended this script to have more than one, it's more efficient to open your output file only one than to re-open it every time you have something to write.

Comment: I have error in looog.err.log: ** (process:11885): WARNING **: nm_client_get_devices: error getting devices: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

Error: Device 'eth0' not found.

Comment: Well, there's your error. Why `nmcli` won't run from cron on your system isn't really a great StackOverflow question -- it's necessarily going to be a fact-intensive investigation -- but I'd start by looking at whether you have SELinux enabled. If you set it to permissive-but-logging mode, that would enable you to find out which permissions are needed but not available.

Comment: ...that error makes it rather clear that bash is working the way it should even from cron, and thus you don't have a variable capture problem, right? Are there any other subsets of the problem in-scope here?

Comment: I run "setenforce 0" and script works perfectly. So the question in the SELinux. Now I going create a rule for SELinux. THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad to help! BTW, I just did an edit to combine the `grep` and `awk` -- there's no reason to have them as separate commands. (The change from `.` to `[.]` is actually needed in grep too, to prevent `.` from acting like a wildcard character).